# Use transaction for multiple save

Tags: transactions, spring-data, rollback

I need to save more entities in my service in one transaction - if one save fails, nothing should be saved. I tried to use @Transactional, but it doesn't work, or I don't know, how to use it :) Correct record is saved and bad record is not saved, I need both not to be saved. How can I achieve that?

My code:

```
public interface MyRecordRepository extends JpaRepository<Record, Long>,
        QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Record> {

}

@Service
public class MyPersisterServiceImpl implements MyPersisterService {...
    @Autowired
    private MyRepository myRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void saveRecords(List<Record> recordList) {
        for(Record r : recordList){
            myRepository.save(record);
        }
    }
...


@EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)
... // other annotations
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
...
```

My env: Spring 4.0.7 with Spring data, querydsl, hibernate, apache tomcat 8, java 8.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is a problem with aspectj configuration, because in proxy mode it works as expected... I mark this question as resolved for now.

Answer (score -2):

I made my transaction works for multiple save like following:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public void service-method( ) throws RestServiceException,Exception{
for(entity,entities) {
     repository1.save(entity)
 }
for(entity2,entities2) {
     repository2.save(entity2)
}
throw new Exception();
}
```

hope that helps.

Comment: 1. Do you think the code you have posted will compile ? 2. Consider formatting your code before posting https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting